# Playback of multiple Audiofiles with NAudio in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, naudio

I'm developing an universal app where several audio streams are played simultaneously. I'd need the ability to change the volume for each of my streams seperately. I tried to use the MixinSampleProvider, as is shown in Mark Heath's [blog entry](http://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio) but I get a com exception when starting playback (in MediaFoundationReaderUniversal). I'm fairly new to NAudio so I'm a bit lost here. I researched already quite a bit but samples concerning UWP are pretty rare. Below is what I have already. What is the correct way/which class should I use?

This is what I have so far:

```
IStorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var player = new WasapiOutRT(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 200);
player.Init(() => { return new MediaFoundationReaderUniversal(stream); });
player.Play();
```

Can I do what I want in an UWP-compatible way?

edit:

this is the exception I get, it's half in german but the important parts are in english. The last part says "interface not supported":

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type  'NAudio.MediaFoundation.IMFSourceReader'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{70AE66F2-C809-4E4F-8915-BDCB406B7993}' failed due to the following error: Schnittstelle nicht unterstützt (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

in MediaFoundationReader.Read pReader.ReadSample(MediaFoundationInterop.MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, 0, out actualStreamIndex, out dwFlags, out timestamp, out pSample);

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: [StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync.aspx): *"You can use this method to access your app's resources using either "ms-appx://" or "ms-appdata://" URIs."*

Comment: @IInspectable: the opening and playback of the asset works, the problem arises when I put a MixinSampleProvider between the reader and the player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself, the problem is when I use a closure for the player.Init() Function, like this:

```
IStorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
var waveChannel32 = new WaveChannel32(new MediaFoundationReaderUniversal(stream));
var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new ISampleProvider[] { waveChannel32.ToSampleProvider() });

_audioOutput = new WasapiOutRT(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 200);
_audioOutput.Init(() =>
{
    return mixer.ToWaveProvider();
});
_audioOutput.Play();
```

when I change above code to this, no COM Exception is thrown and the code runs just fine:

```
IStorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

_audioOutput = new WasapiOutRT(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 200);
_audioOutput.Init(() =>
{
    var waveChannel32 = new WaveChannel32(new MediaFoundationReaderUniversal(stream));
    var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new ISampleProvider[] { waveChannel32.ToSampleProvider() });
    return mixer.ToWaveProvider();
});
_audioOutput.Play();
```

Comment: yes, this is due to a COM threading issue that we would need a post-compilation IL modification step in NAudio to resolve (like SharpDx does)